Form running GET request instead of POST in Django app
I'm having an issue in Django where when I click save on a form, it sends a GET request instead of a POST.
I'm not sure why this is happening, and I've searched about handling forms and POST methods, but I can't seem to figure out what the issue is.
I have added some relevant components below, kindly help.
subir_noticia.html
    {% extends "homepage/base.html" %}
     {% block title %}Estacion Obrera{% endblock %}

     {% block content %}
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"\>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-dark"\>
    </form\>
{% endblock %}

view.py
def crear_noticia(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NoticiaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('ver_noticias_pendietes.html')
    else:
        form = NoticiaForm()
    return render(request, 'administrar_noticias/subir_noticia.html', {'form': form})


terminal
[15/Jul/2024 23:50:30\] "GET /administrar_noticias/subir_noticia/?busqueda=&csrfmiddlewaretoken=6JWbqf0Dgo1AExf6P27MzAPlXc06iyvFquFaZ4ztBJSsa0Z1qjK1F5BXjV1Wg88A&titulo=Prueba&subtitulo=pruebita&categoria=hjkhk&cuerpo_noticia=asda&pie_de_foto=ada&imagen=WhatsApp+Image+2024-07-08+at+23.23.38+%281%29.jpeg&autor=asda HTTP/1.1" 200 5097


urls.py
urlpatterns = \[
path("subir_noticia/", views.crear_noticia, name='subir_noticia'),
path("ver_noticias_pendientes/", views.ver_noticias_pendientes, name='ver_noticias_pendientes'),
\]


forms.py
class NoticiaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Noticia
        fields = ['titulo', 'subtitulo', 'categoria', 'cuerpo_noticia', 'pie_de_foto', 'imagen','autor']
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

models.py
class Noticia(models.Model):
ESTADOS = (
('pendiente', 'Pendiente'),
('publicado', 'Publicado'),
('oculto', 'Oculto'),
)
categoria = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
titulo = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
subtitulo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
cuerpo_noticia = models.TextField()
autor = models.CharField(max_length=255)
imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagenes/noticias/')  
pie_de_foto = models.CharField(max_length=255)
estado = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ESTADOS, default='pendiente')
fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo


Please [edit] and fix the code formatting in your question, you have stray backslashes and incorrect indentation in your code probably due to issues while formatting. Also remove the Spanish text from the question, posts on Stack Overflow should be English only.

Please provide a [mre], your form should get submitted with the POST method, do you have some JavaScript that might be modifying the submission behaviour?

is everything working as expected? you have form action="" empty which means it will submit the form to the same URL of current page. So the point is that your GET request at the end that you are getting, is the result of return render probably. that also means you have a POST request going before this GET request. double check it and reply here.
